# How to add org.jsoup library as module in multimodule project and compile with jlink?

Tags: java, maven, jsoup, jlink, module-info

I'm need help with jlink packaging.
I have a multi module project and use Maven.

Project:
-module1;
-module2;
-module3.

Module3 it's JavaFx and depends on module2. Module2 depends on Jsoup library (from maven repository) and I put as dependency in its pom.xml. Each module (module1, module2, module3) has own module-info.java.

Now, I've created org.jsoup with module-info.class (with jdeps) and put in Project/jars/org.jsoup.jar.

Then deleted dependency Jsoup library (from maven repository) and add my new local file from Project/jars/org.jsoup.jar. Command mvn clean package install works fine, but I want use jlink.

I have an error Module org.jsoup not found, required by module2. Can't understand what I need to do ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you are trying to hack JSoup in order to make it appear as a module by just injecting a self-created module-info.class into it?

Comment: Yes, now I put dependency with compiled local file to POM with Module3 and launched javafx:jlink. It worked.